# How to pass a vector from tableau to R

Tags: tableau-api, rserve

I have a need to pass a vector of arguments to Rserve from tableau. Specifically, I am using IRR calculations in R (on Rserve), and i want to pass vector of cash-flows that are as columns in my table (instead of rows/measure). So, i want to collect all those CF in a vector and pass it on to Rserve. Passing them one at a time slows down IO.

SCRIPT_REAL("r_func(c(.arg1, .arg2, .arg3))",sum(cf1), sum(cf2), sum(cf3))

cf1..cfn are cashflows corresponding to various periods. Above code works well when cf are few but takes a long time when i have few hundereds. Further, time spent is not in calculation but IO when communicating with remote Rserve. If i have a local Rserve, this calculation happens under few seconds while on remote, it takes well over a minute.

Also, want to point out that tableau / Rserve, set one argument after another and that takes time. My expectation is that once i have a vector, it would be just 1 transfer and setting of arguments, and therefore this should speed up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step in understanding how Tableau interacts with R or Python, is understanding how Tableau's table calcs work.

Tableau Script_XXX() functions are table calculations which means that you invoke them on a **vector** of aggregate query results and the corresponding R or Python code needs to return a **vector** usually of the same size. (I think you may be able to return a scalar or smaller vector which gets replicated to appear like a vector of the same size as the argument -- but not certain)

You can control how your data is partitioned into vectors, and also the ordering of data in the vectors, by editing the table calc to specify the ***partitioning and addressing*** for that calc.

Partitioning determines how your aggregate query results are broken up into vectors for calculation purposes. Addressing determines how the elements of each vector are ordered. You can either do that based on the physical layout of the table structure, or (better) based on the specific dimensions.

See the [Tableau on-line help for table calcs](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_tablecalculations.htm) for more info, and look online training videos from Tableau or blog entries (especially from anyone named Bora)

One way to test your understanding of these concepts is create a Tableau table (i.e., a viz with a mark type of text) with several dimensions on row and column shelves. Then create calculated fields for INDEX() and SIZE() and display them on text. Finally, change the partitioning and addressing in different ways by editing those table calcs. Try several different permutations. When you can confidently predict what those functions will produce for different settings, then you're ready to do more complex tasks - such as talking to R.

It is also instructive to experiment with FIRST(), LAST(), LOOKUP(), WINDOW_SUM() etc -- and finally dig into PREVIOUS_VALUE(). Warning, PREVIOUS_VALUE() is a bit odd, and  does not behave the way you probably assume it does. Still, it is a useful technique that can implement a recursive calculation, and is about as close to a for loop as Tableau gets.